# Google Cache CSS and HTML files are out-of-sync

Tags: google, html, css, cache

I am monitoring the cached version of the main [page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&biw=1280&bih=657&sclient=psy-ab&q=cache%3ayourworldclocks.juplo.com&oq=cache%3ayourworldclocks.juplo.com&gs_l=hp.3..0i20l2j0l2.1746.17485.0.18185.50.39.7.4.7.0.288.1857.0j4j5.9.0.les;..0.30...1c.1.3.psy-ab.r6LxnTT8-EA&pbx=1) of one of my sites. I have noticed something strange.

Obviously, the cached pages is displayed with the latest CSS file. Yet, the page content is quite oudated.

How come? Is there anything I can do about it or should I just wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that by adding a proper `lastmod` tag for the corresponding page in my `sitemap.xml` (which is registered in my `robots.txt`) and by updating it when the page was modified, the cache has been updated correctly after some days. I also see the impact in Google Webmaster.

Answer (score 2):

**Google Caches only HTML content**

I believe that Google only caches the HTML content and additional files like JS/CSS/Images are still required to display the cache correctly. If you was to rename an image or css file completely you should notice that cache alters as well. But you can't change the HTML Content no mater what you do until they refresh their system.

**A quick test**

A quick test on this theory would be to quickly rename your CSS file breaking it temporary and quickly refresh the cache page and see the result. CTRL+F5 (Hard Refresh).

**Don't Worry About Google Cache**

I wouldn't concern yourself to much on the Google Cache its not really important, it's useful for using when sites are down or when deletions occur you can recover a lot of the HTML data. In terms of rankings, no effect whats so ever.

**Please Note:**

> Cached: Google crawls the web and takes snapshots of each page. When
>   you click Cached, you'll see the webpage as it looked when we last
>   indexed it.

The above snippet from the [Google cache link](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1055571) may imply that its when your page was last indexed this is simply untrue, the cache service Google offer is often days behind the algorithms itself. And a prime example of this is when you post something in your blog or create another page on your site your often see that your page is indeed indexed yet there is NO CACHE PAGED - Which is a clear indication that the cache system is not real time as the algorithms.

Comment: I disagree, Google explicitely says that it uses the cache version for indexing. In my case, I have removed a keyword issue, which impacts the indexing, and therefore ranking.

Comment: Please could you link me the source where it explicitly says that Google uses Google Cache for indexing… Since Google often indexes pages before Google cache and the fact that Google cache is many days behind the everyday algorithms I find this hard to believe. I think you have read wrongly unless you can prove me otherwise and then I’ll eat my shorts.

Comment: Here it is: http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/features_list.html#cached -> It says: If you click on the "Cached" link, you will see the web page as it looked when we indexed it.

Comment: Updated my answer, its simply not true. The cache is not real time.

Comment: A prime example displaying that this simply is not true…  http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmasters.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F43772%2Fgoogle-cache-css-and-html-files-are-out-of-sync%2F&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&client=firefox-a&oq=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmasters.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F43772%2Fgoogle-cache-css-and-html-files-are-out-of-sync%2F&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...154304.156543.0.156927.12.6.0.0.0.0.65.65.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.vquHClANph0 notice how the page is indexed yet no cache? Cache is not real time

Comment: I did not claim the cache is real time. What Google seems to say, is that it is a necessary step before indexing. In our case, we are dealing with stackoverflow and I can't find any stackoverflow page in search results having a cache link (even old pages). Google probably disabled it. Since people update questions and answers too often, it would drive the cache system nuts without real added value for the end user... Bon appetit? lol!

Comment: Simply not true again, Take a look at old pages on stack overflow or even this site. Your find they are cached. Caches depending on your site size can take weeks, months. Its by far not real time and its not used in rankings. the term last 'indexed' refers to the last time we indexed the 'cache'

Comment: to test this theory on webmasters or stack overflow click questions and sort by votes, questions with more votes are the older ones 'Generally' but not always.

Comment: True some SO pages are in the cache. For me, SO may have used no-cache on some of its pages or Google's cache may not display all of its content. I have managed to update the cache for my page, and I can see the impact on keywords in Google Webmaster Tool. As far as I am concerned, the cache content is used as the source for indexing. I can see it in my keywords...

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools is often days behind on links, clicks, rankings, keywords and so on.. just like the caching service. Googles ranking algorithms is much faster as they are higher priority and rightfully so as this is Google is the best since news gets updated faster than other search engines. More evidence search results hy hour and you see the avg sites are not cached and wont be for hours to days.